# Trouble creating a data store on ESXI 6.5 u1

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hardware-raid, datastore

I have a RAID 6 array (HP p822 controller v8.0 firmware) that I just added to my ESXI server. When I went to create a new data store I noticed it showed  2.92gb free of 10.92tb. This is a new array, so the disk should be blank, when I try to create the array I get this message under "Select partitioning options":

[missing "en-us.storage.partitionTypes.E3C9E3160B5C4DB8817DF92DF00215AE" translation] (128 MB)

If I click create the browser crashes with this error (it happens in chrome,firefox, and edge)

Cause: TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of null
Version: 1.21.0
Build: 5724747
ESXi: 6.5.0
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36

Exception stack:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of null
    at $scope.wizardOptions.currentPage.onCommit (192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:359:13125)
    at onCommit (192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:462:3976)
    at Object.onNextClick (/192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:462:4168)
    at b.$scope.onNextClick (192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:462:7155)
    at 192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:321:23160
    at 192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:428:24773
    at b.$eval (192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:320:17497)
    at b.$apply (192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:320:17723)
    at HTMLButtonElement. (192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:428:24755)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (192.168.1.60/ui/scripts/main.js:317:14464)

I had to remove "https://" from before all of the 192. addresses in quotes because I can't post with that many links.

I tried googling the initial error, but I didn't get any results that helped. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, I had to go to the Devices section under Storage (with EDGE cause Chrome crashes on right click). I had to clear the partition table. I tried to create the datastore again, this time I could see the partition was represented properly in the picture and there was no error, but I could not get the partition to create because every time I tried it would the web client would crash. I went back to Chrome and was able to create the datastore properly.

Basically every time something doesn't work in 6.5U1 I have to browser juggle.

EDIT: I am really sad that vmware took away the desktop clients in favor of a browser only solution, in theory it was a nice idea, but the browser client clearly isn't there yet, and that can cause major issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the vSphere client?  I had a very similar issue trying to access datastores after upgrading from 5.0 to 6.5u1 (note:  not a supported path).  Could not add a host's 2nd datastore from a browser (remember HTML5 is beta, Flash is supported).  Didn't have flash on the machine I was using so I went in with the vSphere client, was able to add the datastore.

Comment: with 6.5 U1 I was under the impression that they moved away from the client, so this is new to me. Do you have a link to a 6.5 U1 client? if so I   would love to try. The client I have that I thought was up to date does not work

Comment: I agree with that.  I have 4.1-6.0 installed on my laptop, guessing I got in with the 6.0 version.

Comment: Specifically I have v6.0.0.5505 installed and I still have the host's IP saved in my list of recent connections.  The server is 6.5.0 build 4564106.  Trying to recreate now...

Comment: I was trying to add the 2nd datastore on the host.  I could re-scan from the web-client.  Could not "add" an existing datastore.  I was not creating a new datastore.    With the old # client, I was able to go in and "add" existing storage from Configuration > Storage.  I just confirmed with client version 6.0.0.5505 on a new install.  The host with the storage problem was a PowerEdge T710 upgraded from 5.0.0.  I was also able to connect to a fresh install of the same version on a PowerEdge T630.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I am running 6.5.0 Update 1 (Build 5969303) from a fresh install It won't let me run the client anymore. From this KB it looks like I won't be able to do that: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2147929    Is there any other way to do this? I feel like the error I see first: [missing "en-us.storage.partitionTypes.E3C9E3160B5C4DB8817DF92DF00215AE" translation] (128 MB) is not browser related, and might have something to do with the way the data store is being seen by ESXI